# Can you classify data sent over jdbc using Java Prepared Statements as encrypted?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, encryption, jdbc

I have a java application that connects to an external sql database using jdbc 4. It uses prepared statements to select data from the database and also to send updates. Can the data that's transferred between the database and my application be classified as encrypted or are there further steps I would need to take in my application for it to be encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PreparedStatement does not equate to encryption.  You would need to enable (better yet if you can require it;  my familiarity is with postgresql rather than mysql) SSL on the server and set up a certificate and private key.  You would then need to instruct your application to use SSL and to accept (only) the certificate belonging to the server.

Note that SSL and encryption in transit, while useful, does not protect the data from an attacker who gains access to the database.

---

PS. Most likely [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) would be the best resource for answers regarding how to configure mysql.

---

**Edit for follow on:** According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security-against-attack.html) the credentials in the initial connection are secured.

Comment: so just to follow on from that when the application creates the initial connection to the database the connection details (db name, u/n, p/w) would be pretty easy to pick up if anyone was watching for them without ssl?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll take a look at the ServerFault site